# How to pass value from initstate to widgets in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget, flutter-listview

In my application, I  made an api call on initstate, I was able to retrive the response data

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _dbHelper.getAllUserData().then((value)async{
      userdetails = value;
      await getsubjectList(value[0].userId!, value[0].accountId!).then((value){
        testfunction(value);
      });
    });
  }
```

I need to pass its response to a ListViewBuilder to display that values on the application, How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Declare a list in your class:

```
List<YourObject> list = [];
```

Set your values in the list (better create a function that populates the list:

```
fetchData() {
   List<YourObject> tempList = ... get the data ...;

   setState(() { list = tempList; });
}
```

Call `fetchData` in your `initState()`.

Then create the ListView:

```
   ListView.builder(
        itemCount: list.length,
        physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return ListTile(
            title: Text("${list[index].toString()}")
            );
        }
    ),
```

Also I hope you have a Stateful widget and not Stateless.

Answer (score 0):

At first you call the length of your list in `itemCount`, Here I return the list builder with `ListTile` you can change it your custom design:

Init section:

```
List<YourModelClass> subjectList = [];
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _dbHelper.getAllUserData().then((value)async{
      userdetails = value;
       // subjectList.add(value); // store the user item 
      await getsubjectList(value[0].userId!, value[0].accountId!).then((value){
        testfunction(value);
      });
    });
  }
```

Body:

```
body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: subjectList.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: ScrollPhysics()
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
          return ListTile(
            title:Text("${subjectList[index].itemName}")
            );
        }
        ),
```

Comment: Do I need to store response to a list first??

Comment: in init section you store the data first

Answer (score 0):

1- Create a private variable `var _response;`

2- In your initState set a value to your **_response** variable by using **setState**

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
       setState(() {
        _response = yourApiResponse;
       });
  }
```

3- use the **_response** in your listView.builder widget

```
body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _response.length,
        itemBuilder: (context,index){
          return ListTile(
            title:Text(_response[index].Name)
            );
        }
        ),
```